# Integration of sin x dx problem in python programming implementation

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-integration

I want to implement this integration in Python:

[image: Equation]

So far I did the code below but it is not making sense. What am I doing wrong?

```
import sympy as sm
x=sm.Symbol('x')
x=sm.integrate(math.sin(x)**2, 2*x)
```

Comment: " but it is not making sense" -> can you be more specific about what it's giving you and why it's not making sense?

Comment: "can't convert expression to float" the error its throwing and code doesnt match original equation, and no limits are define

Comment: Are you aware that the equation you have shown has `sin(x ** 2)` but in the code you are using `sin(x) ** 2`?

Comment: ok i changed but it still throws same error

Comment: Please include the errors in the question (you can edit it); they will be easier to read thatn in comments.  We like to see evidence that posters are trying to understand the errors.

Comment: @SUM You can help others help you by telling exactly what you entered, what you expected, and what you got. Also, what are you trying to do. I see several people are heroically trying to guess what's going on here, and I can tell you're not satisfied with that. Well, there's nothing gained by making people guess.

Comment: sorry ok let me see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the other answers you don't need to use `trigintegrate` but you do need to supply the integration limits when calling `integrate` if it is a definite integral:

```
In [31]: from sympy import integrate, sin, oo, Symbol

In [32]: x = Symbol('x')

In [33]: integrate(sin(x**2), (x, 0, oo))
Out[33]: 
√2⋅√π
─────
  4  

In [34]: _.n()
Out[34]: 0.626657068657750
```

Comment: invalid limitation is throwing

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what your comment means.

Answer (score 3):

One issue was that you didn't use the trig functions from sympy:

```
from sympy import sin
from sympy.abc import x

integrate(sm.sin(x**2), x)
```

This will return a complicated expression involving the Gamma function because `sin(x^2)` has no simple indefinite integral.

You can, however, directly compute the *definite* integral you are showing, simply by using the bounds as argument (and using `sympy.oo` for infinity):

```
from sympy import sin, oo
from sympy.abc import x

integrate(sin(x**2), (x, 0, oo))
```

This returns properly: [image: √2√π/4].

(source: from the [sympy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html))

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: yes indeed, it returns nothing because there is no 'indefinite integral' for the function sin(x^2). Let me a  minute to edit my answer

Comment: @SUM Are you running the latest version of sympy (`1.7.1`)? Also, try not to use `x` both as a symbol and as the variable for the expression.

Comment: @SUM I tried this code directly in the sympy documentation online python console

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
import sympy as sm

x=sm.Symbol('x')
x=sm.integrate(sm.sin(x**2), x)

print(x)
```

You need to use the sin function from sympy lib instead of math lib.

Comment: 32⎯⎯√⎯⎯√(2√√)Γ(34)8Γ(74) ---------i tried your code it gives this

Answer (score 1):

It helps a great deal to know what the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20sin%28x%5E2%29%20from%200%20to%20infinity) is before you begin computing:

integral_0^∞ sin(x^2) dx = sqrt(π/2)/2≈0.626657

Comment: i want to pass 10 different values of x through equation direct answer will not help